# How to group total amount spend based on both ID and name

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table where

```
patientId  | Units | Amount | PatientName
1234       |   1   |   20   |lisa
1111       |   5   |   10   |john
1234       |   10  |   200  |lisa
345        |  2     |   30  | xyz
```

i want to get ID in one column, then patient name then total amount spent by him on different items,

please note i have got patient name in the column above by doing a join on 2 tables using ID as the key

i am doing this to get this table

```
select t1.*,t2.name from table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

then for adding i am trying to use the `group by` clause but that gives an error

please note i cannot use temp table in this, only need to do this using subquery, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `group by`?

```
select t1.patientid, t2.patientname, sum(t1.amount)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.patientid, t2.patientname;
```

Comment: how do i get `t` i can't use temp table

Comment: I would assume that `t` represents *your* table, @SakshamJain . `t`, in the above, isn't a temporary object; in T-SQL temporary object names are prefix with a has (`#`).

Comment: but that is what i am saying in question, i don't have the table i have posted in the question stored anywhere, it is made of two tables t1 and t2 so i can't just name it t

Comment: @SakshamJain Just put your `inner join` instead of `t`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select t1.*,
t2.name 
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id, t2.name
```

What are table1 and table2 like? What's the error message?

Comment: Is this an answer, or are you asking for clarification here? If the latter, then that should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: t1 is a table having id, units, amount and t2 is a table having id, name the error when i run your query is `table1.amount is invalid because in either an aggregate function or group by clause`